# Dynamic SQL Not working - Complies , but errors out

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TSQL_DLOOKUP](
    [LookUpTable] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [LookUpField] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [LookUpValue] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [LookUpDecode] [nchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


The procedure:

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyDLookUp]
@LookUpValue NCHAR(10),
@LookUpTable NCHAR(10),
@LookUpField NCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParameterDefinition AS NVARCHAR(100)
/* Build Transact-SQL String by including the parameter */
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT LookUpDecode FROM TSQL_DLOOKUP WHERE LookUpTable = @LookUpTable AND LookUpValue = @LookUpValue AND LookUpField =@LookUpField' 
/* Execute Transact-SQL String */
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @LookUpValue,@LookUpTable,@LookUpField
END
```

`enter code here`        To run:

```
    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[MyDLookUp]
            @LookUpValue = N'F',
            @LookUpTable = N'LCLASS',
            @LookUpField = N'CLASS'


 SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value


    The error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near 'F'.
    Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
    Must declare the scalar variable "@LookUpTable".



The code compiles, but will not run. Please help.
```

The idea here is to as accurately as possible replicate the MSACCESS DLOOOKUP function. I am on a project in which a lot of repeated SQL statements exist where the coder before me did it this way, I need to simplify things.

Comment: I don't see the need of using dynamic SQL here at all

Answer (score 3):

As said by LAMAK Clearly there is no need of Dynamic query here u can do the same by using staic query!!

```
SELECT lookupdecode 
FROM   tsql_dlookup 
WHERE  lookuptable = @LookUpTable 
       AND lookupvalue = @LookUpValue 
       AND lookupfield = @LookUpField
```

Function to do the same job

```
CREATE FUNCTION dlookup(@LookUpValue NCHAR(10),
@LookUpTable NCHAR(10),
@LookUpField NCHAR(10))
RETURNS nchar
AS
BEGIN
    declare @lookupdecode nchar(50)
      SELECT  top 1 @lookupdecode = lookupdecode 
    FROM   tsql_dlookup 
    WHERE  lookuptable = @LookUpTable 
           AND lookupvalue = @LookUpValue 
           AND lookupfield = @LookUpField 

   RETURN @lookupdecode 
END;
```

Comment: Ok ...changed my code and it works....however got any ideas how to turn this into a function ?

Comment: @AnthonyParker - Check now

Comment: this returns a table, i need it to return nchar

Comment: @AnthonyParker changed function to return nchar

Comment: This fails with a syntax error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure dlookup, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'nchar'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure dlookup, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@lookupdecode".

Comment: @AnthonyParker Jeez dude, please try to do a little debugging by yourself too

Comment: @AnthonyParker My bad check now...But you can fix these bugs easily try to understand how scalar function works

Comment: It compiles, however it is not seen as a function?

select *, dlookup('F','LCLASS','CLASS') from DUAL_TEST_TABLE

shows dlookup as not recognized

Comment: @AnthonyParker for a scalar function you need to use the schema prefix

Comment: @AnthonyParker select *,schemaname.dlookup('F','LCLASS','CLASS')  from tablename

Comment: oK, FAT FINGERED SOMEWHERE AND IT RETURNS RESULTS...WRONG ONES , BUT GETTING THERE, I GETTING @LookUpValue BACK

Comment: @AnthonyParker Ok, this question is starting to devolve heavily into a "fix my code for me", which is not what SO is for. This answer addresses correctly your issue as described on your question

Comment: Agreed. It has me where I want to go and answers several issues, however the changes I have used get me halfway there ...and are 100% different than when I started. If only someone could tell me why the code returns the wrong value ........It does seem to be correct

Comment: @AnthonyParker Exactly, it seems to be correct, so how could we help you without seeing the data in your table?, maybe your table has the wrong values, we can't know

Comment: The lookup table:

  (N'LCLASS', N'CLASS', N'F', N'FARM'),
  (N'LCLASS', N'CLASS', N'E', N'EXEMPT'),
  (N'LCLASS', N'CLASS', N'R', N'RESIDENTIAL'),
  (N'LTYPE', N'ASMTYPE', N'F', N'FORCED'),
  (N'LTYPE', N'ASMTYPE', N'R', N'RENDERED')
GO

Comment: @AnthonyParker Happy u got the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `@params` parameter from the [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SP_EXECUTESQL_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) command which defines the parameters being passed in:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, 
    N'@LookUpValue [nchar](10),@LookUpTable [nchar](10),@LookUpField [nchar](10)',
    @LookUpValue,@LookUpTable,@LookUpField
```

Answer (score 1):

As other said in this case there is no need of dynamic sql as it can be executed directly.

For answer to your question, see below.

The parameter definition needed to be passed as an argument to sp_executesql SP to pass parameters to a dynamic query http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx.

So, your new SP will be as follows

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyDLookUp]
@LookUpValue NCHAR(10),
@LookUpTable NCHAR(10),
@LookUpField NCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParameterDefinition AS NVARCHAR(100)
/* Build Transact-SQL String by including the parameter */
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT LookUpDecode FROM TSQL_DLOOKUP WHERE LookUpValue = @LookUpValue AND LookUpTable = @LookUpTable AND  LookUpField =@LookUpField' 

DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@LookUpValue NCHAR(10), @LookUpTable NCHAR(10), @LookUpField NCHAR(10)';

/* Execute Transact-SQL String */
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @ParmDefinition, @LookUpValue,@LookUpTable,@LookUpField
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code, if this work for you because there is no need to use Dynamic SQL for simple select statment

---------------------------------------Stored Procedure

```
    Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyDLookUp] --[dbo].[MyDLookUp] 1,2,3
    @LookUpValue NCHAR(10),
    @LookUpTable NCHAR(10),
    @LookUpField NCHAR(10)
    AS
    BEGIN        

    SELECT LookUpDecode FROM TSQL_DLOOKUP 
    WHERE LookUpTable = @LookUpTable AND LookUpValue = @LookUpValue AND LookUpField =@LookUpField

    END
```